# ReactJS Is it normal when I use Redux all of my components are class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, components

When I was learning react my instructor always remind me that I should use functional component as many as possible, try to avoid using class component, use class component sparingly. Yeah it was easy back then.

Now I am using Redux and I can barely using functional component because `connect()` imported from react-redux will only work with class component, as a result every component of my app are all class component. Is this normal? Since nowadays hooks API (which is using functional component) increasing in popularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 2 things:

Firstly, it *is* possible to [`connect` a functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857738/mapstatetoprops-for-functional-component).

Secondly, you shouldn't be connecting every component to Redux. In reality the less components connected to Redux the better. Ideally, for a set of components, you have a 'container' component which is connected to the store (and which contains all the other relevant state and logic within it), then it passes that stuff down to the functional/class component children (which are more focused on presentation). Then you can have a few of these containers throughout the app, and the rest of the components are just traditional React ones.

If you connect everything directly to the store it can lead to problems like decreased reusability of components, poor performance or encouragement of bad component layout/hierarchy.

Comment: I don't know why, a couple weeks ago I tried to use connect() in functional component it threw me an error. But this time I try again it works.

As for the reason I prefer to use connect() in most of the components is as has been mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34307553/9177853

Comment: Connecting leaf components is actually encouraged and increases performance but as with everything, should be reasonable in usage.

Comment: You can connect() to functional components but not to just functions. i.e if your function doesn't return valid jsx, connect will throw an error because it has no way of updating the UI.